# Properties for custom control using in .NET Compact framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, properties

I could able to display my custom controls properties in the property window (using EditorBrowsable() attribute). But I have another property which has class as it's return type. So the same property appearing in the window as read only format. I need property it should take the class values at design time
just like,

```
Font
    Name="Verdana"
    Size="12"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using EditorBrowsable() use:

```
System.ComponentModel.Browsable()
System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue()
System.ComponentModel.Category()
```

The DefaultValue will tell the design that the property has a default value and wont try to set it unless changed.  The Category puts your property in a specific category.  These two properties aren't needed but are nice to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
    I was asking in .net compact framework 2.0